# Laravel 7 Sanctum: Same domain (*.herokuapp.com) but separate React SPA gets CSRF Token Mismatch

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-7, csrf-token, laravel-sanctum

I've read a lot from this forum and watched a lot of tutorial videos on **how to connect separate React/Vue SPA to Laravel API with Sanctum Auth** but none of the solutions worked for me. This is for my school project.

So here's what I did so far.

I created 2 folders, one for api and one for frontend. I installed Laravel on the api folder and installed React app on the frontend folder. Both of these are Git initialized and have their own Github repositories. Also, both of them are deployed to Heroku.

**API**

> Repository: `https://github.com/luchmewep/jarcalc_api`
>
> Website: `https://jarcalc-api.herokuapp.com`

**Front-end**

> Repository: `https://github.com/luchmewep/jarcalc_front`
>
> Website: `https://jarcalculator.herokuapp.com`

**On local**, everything runs fine. I can set error messages to email and password fields on the front-end so that means I have received and sent the **laravel_session** and **XSRF_TOKEN cookies**. I have also displayed the authenticated user's information on a dummy dashboard so **everything works fine on local**.

**On the internet**, both my apps run but won't communicate with each other. In the official documentation, they must at least be on the **same domain** and in this case, they are subdomains of the same domain which is **.herokuapp.com**.

Here are my environment variables for each Heroku apps.

**API**

> SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS = jarcalculator.herokuapp.com
>
> (I've tried adding "SESSION_DRIVER=cookie" and "SESSION_DOMAIN=.herokuapp.com" but still not working!)

### Update

Found out that axios is not carrying XSRF-TOKEN when trying to POST request for /login. It is automatically carried on local testing.

Here is the relevant code:

**api.tsx**

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

**Login.tsx**

```js
...
const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let login = { email: email.value, password: password.value };
    api.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((res) => {
      api.post("/login", login).then((res) => {
        /**
         * goes here if login succeeds...
         */
        console.log("Login Success");
        ...
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Login failed...")
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log("CSRF failed...");
    });
  };
```

**UPDATE**

> ".herokuapp.com is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List. This list is used in recent versions of several browsers, such as Firefox, Chrome and Opera, to limit how broadly a cookie may be scoped. In other words, in browsers that support the functionality, applications in the herokuapp.com domain are prevented from setting cookies for *.herokuapp.com."
>   *https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com*

**COOKIES ON LOCAL**
[image]

**COOKIES ON DEPLOYED**
[image]

Explanation: Although the API and frontend both have **.herokuapp.com**, that does not make them *on the same domain*. It is explained on Heroku's article above. This means that all requests between ***.herokuapp.com** are considered **cross-site** instead of **same-site**.

**SOLUTION**

Since **laravel_session** cookie is being carried by axios, the only problem left is the **xsrf-token** cookie. To solve the problem, one must buy a domain name and set the subdomain name for each. In my case, my React frontend is now at [www.jarcalculator.me](http://www.jarcalculator.me) while my Laravel backend is now at [api.jarcalculator.me](http://api.jarcalculator.me). Since they are now same-site regardless of where they are deployed (React moved to Github pages while Laravel at Heroku), the cookie can be set automatically.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214463/discussion-on-question-by-james-carlo-luchavez-laravel-7-sanctum-same-domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally fixed my problem by claiming my free domain name via Github Student Pack. I set my React app's domain name to www.jarcalculator.me while I set my Laravel app's domain name to api.jarcalculator.me. Since they are now subdomains of the same domain which is jarcalculator.me, passing of cookie that contains the CSRF-token and laravel_session token is **automatic**. No need for modification on axios settings. Just setting the axios' **withCredentials** to true is all you need to do.